# How to append token in Angular Dropzone.js

Tags: angular, dropzone.js

I have used ngx-dropzone-wrapper for creating a dropzone for a pdf upload after login via token authentication-
The dropzone config is present in app.module.ts as follows-

```
 const DROPZONE_CONFIG: DropzoneConfigInterface = {
  method: "get",
  url: 'http://9666427d.ngrok.io/api/fileentry/add?token=',
  maxFilesize: 2,
  maxFiles: 1,
  acceptedFiles: '.pdf'
};
```

I wish to append token with this url, I have a service with following function to get token-

```
  getToken() {
return this.LoginResponse.token;
}
```

Dropzone is present in component HTML as follows-

```
  <dropzone [message]="'Click or drag Synopsis PDF here to upload - Max Allowed Size (2MB) '" id="dropzone"></dropzone>
```

I could not figure out how to append token in url given in app module. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Begin by importing the following package classes.

```
import { DROPZONE_CONFIG } from 'ngx-dropzone-wrapper';
import { DropzoneConfigInterface } from 'ngx-dropzone-wrapper';
```

Create a variable in the component class that uses the ngx-dropzone-wrapper package.

```
config: DropzoneConfigInterface = { };
```

Then append your token within the constructor:

```
constructor(private api: ApiService) {
  this._fetchFiles();
  this.config = {
      url: this.api._getUploadFilesEndPoint()+"?token="+this.api._getToken(),
      method: 'post',
      maxFilesize: 1,
      clickable: true,
      acceptedFiles: '.pdf,'       
    };
}
```